# Menu callback rendering node xxx

Tags: 7, nodes, routes

I want to render node/7 on /mymodule/info. I don't want to use path to cover it. What callback function shall I use?

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodule/info'] = array(
    'title' => t('My module'),
    'description' => t('My module description'),
    'page callback' => ?????????,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the same callback issued from `node/%node` menu i.e. node_page_view :

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodule/info'] = array(
    'title' => t('My module'),
    'description' => t('My module description'),
    'page callback' => 'node_7',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}


function node_7(){

include_once(drupal_get_path('module','node') . '/node.pages.inc');

return node_page_view(node_load('7'));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['mymodule/info'] = array(
    'title' => t('My module'),
    'description' => t('My module description'),
    'page callback' => 'rendernodeseven',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}


function rendernodeseven() {
    print_r(node_load(7));
}
```